# R: filter dataframe rows if values are not in another list

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
     Element     Error
1    A           Grid error
2    B           Meteo error
3    C           Gen error
4    D           Blade error
```

I would like to filter it, keeping only the rows in which the values in the `Error` column are not in the following list `["Grid error", "Meteo error"]`

So my expected output is:

```
     Element     Error
1    C           Gen error
2    D           Blade error
```

Comment: `data[!(data$Error %in% c("Grid error","Meteo error")),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
 subset(data, !Error %in% c("Grid error","Meteo error"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` in `dplyr` (package in the `tidyverse`):

```
example_df <- data.frame(element = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                     Error = c("Grid error", "Meteo error",
                     "Gen error", "Blade error"))

removals <- list("Grid error", "Meteo error")


output_df <- example_df %>%
  filter(!(Error %in% removals))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a pointer in the right direction, with function `filter` in `dplyr`. But with `!` right next to the vector `Error`.

```
example_df <-  data.frame(element = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
               Error = c("Grid error", "Meteo error","Gen error",
                         "Blade error"))
  removals <- list("Grid error", "Meteo error")
  output_df <- df %>%  
    filter(!Error %in% removals)
```